# Windows 8 mail app didn't show sender name

Tags: c#, windows, email, sendmail, sendkeys

I have some problem.
So, I created app in C# that sending email and have a problem with Windows 8 Mail app. This is very good app, but I can't understand, why this app doesn't want to show my sender name ( mean email from my app). Other services - ok. Showing. But if I send mail from my gmail account (and I use this accout in my app, but doesn't matter from where i send, gmail page or my app) to hotmail - app doesn't show. only - javapaulfox@gmail.com. But on page hotmail.com everything is ok(as in Android app on my tablet), I see Pavel instead javapaulfox@gmail.com. 
So, maybe someone know template for this app? Becouse problem only with this app.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the email address, e.g. "Paval <javapaulfox@...com>", it sounds like you are just using "javapaulfox@...com").

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: Ok, I understand. This is my code:
WebMail.From = new MailAddress("javapaulfox@gmail.com", "Pavel").ToString();
the same string like WebMail.From = "Pavel <javapaulfox@gmail.com>" also doesn't work. But I want to emphasize that my code doesn't work only with Windows 8 Mail app. With internet pages and others app everything is ok